# Textarea shows extra space while retrieving from database?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a simple php file that gets info from mysql database display inside textarea but when I open it from browsers it shows extra space at the beginning and end of the text inside textarea

this is how it looks (database text has no extra space)
[image]

this is what I did to retrieve the text

```
<textarea name="text" rows="9">
    <?php echo $fetchedData['founder_msg']; ?>
</textarea>
```

I used simple mysql_fetch_array to retrieve the value 
text are saved inside founder_msg field in mysql database of data type text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're inserting a lot of white-space with your formatting. Try the following instead:

```
<textarea name="text" rows="9"><?php 
    echo trim( $fetchedData['founder_msg'] ); // trim, following comments
?></textarea>
```

Comment: @monk Try adding `trim()` around the data.

Comment: i will, man . i was going to do that earlier. but you know stackoverflow doesn't let me do that before as it was too early

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
<textarea name="text" rows="9"><?=trim($fetchedData['founder_msg'])?></textarea>
```